# how to add an increase of pictures fotorama plugin

Tags: jquery, fotorama

I try to add the increase of pictures by clicking in plugin fotorama.
I use this code for increase active image, but this code work for all element on the page.

```
jQuery("div:contains('fotorama__stage__frame fotorama__fade-rear fotorama__loaded     fotorama__loaded--img fotorama__active'):contains('img .fotorama__img')").click(function () {
    var o=jQuery(this).parent();
    var url= jQuery("div:contains('--img fotorama__active')").find('img').attr('src');  
    var html='<a href="" class="clone"><img src="'+url+'" /></a>'
    o.append(html);
    o=o.find('.clone');
    o.animate({});
    console.log('click');
    o.click(function () {
        jQuery('.clone').remove();
    });
});
```

How fix this bug?
http://arngoldt.com/?page_id=18 - example of my code on this page.

Answer (score 0):

You use a very strange selectors. Try to use `jQuery(".fotorama__img").click(...)` and `jQuery(".fotorama__stage__shaft .fotorama__active img")`. Also, looks like you should use `fotorama:showend` event for receive a big image src, because it renders asynchronously. For more information see [documentation page](http://fotorama.io/customize/api/).

Comment: Sergey,thank's for advice. I use the fotorama:load event.But I don't understand how to apply click only to the big picture. Now click function work for next+prev button and thumb images.

Comment: This selector `jQuery(".fotorama__stage__frame.fotorama__loaded.fotorama__loaded--img.fotorama__active img")` returns only big picture. Try to use it.

Comment: Also you can use fotorama API for access to the active big image. You can do it something like this `jQuery(".fotorama").data("fotorama").activeFrame.$stageFrame`

Comment: Thank's. This problem solved, but another problem occurred. I see two click om console log + two object with class="clone".